# How do I check for multiple date formats in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, datetime

I am looking in a string to pull 2 date values in the format mm/dd/yyyy, m/d/yyyy, m/dd/yyyy, or mm/d/yyyy.  How do I add that condition to my Regex?

```
private static readonly Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
```

Comment: Please post an example of your string, where the values are in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static readonly Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}");
```

**Edit:** After obtaining initial matches, attempt to parse them using `DateTime.TryParse` to verify that they are indeed valid dates.  Otherwise your regex will need to be significantly more complex (see Jeff the Bear's answer).

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this `(option1|option2)`

The `|` is an OR.

**BUT** reading your examples, I don't think you need it. Try this instead.

```
(?<month>[0-9]{1,2})\/(?<day>[0-9]{1,2})\/(?<year>[0-9]{4})
```

In the `{n,m}` clause, `n` is the minimum number that must be matched while `m` is the maximum number.

***NOTE:** there's a comment on a post around here somewhere that talks about using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` since `\d` can also match some unicode characters.*

Comment: +1 to myself for explaining the `{n,m}` expression which is what the OP needed.

Answer (score 0):

With an "OR". In Regex "|":

```
"(regex1 | regex2)"
```

like:

```
Regex dateRegex = new Regex(@"(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}|\d{1,2}\.d{1,2}\.d{1,4})");
```